# How to handle CORS in NestJs Fastify

Tags: angular, nestjs

I am trying to handle CORS in an Angular application. In my `main.ts`:

```
const adapter = new FastifyAdapter();
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, adapter);
app.enableCors();
```

But my angular client produces CORS errors.

Is this is a bug in NestJS?

Comment: Please add some error output from your angular app console.

Answer (score 3):

```
const CORS_OPTIONS = {
    origin: ['http://127.0.0.1:5500'], // or '*' or whatever is required
    allowedHeaders: [
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Origin',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'Accept',
    'Content-Type',
    'Authorization',
  ],
  exposedHeaders: 'Authorization',
  credentials: true,
  methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
};

const adapter = new FastifyAdapter();
adapter.enableCors(CORS_OPTIONS) //<------------ this line 
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, 
adapter);
//app.enableCors(); <-- remove this line and you should see cors enabled ; also fastify documentation has all the options documentation
```

[image]

Comment: Still getting this warning: `FastifyWarning.fastify-cors: fastify-cors has been deprecated. Use @fastify/cors@7.0.0 instead.`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The approach with fastify-cors didn't work as of 2023

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install the [`fastify-cors`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors) package:

```
npm i fastify-cors
```

Then, in your code:

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-cors'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.register(require('fastify-cors'), {
    origin: true,
    allowedHeaders: [
        'Origin', 
        'X-Requested-With', 
        'Accept', 
        'Content-Type', 
        'Authorization'
    ],
    methods: ['GET', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  });
```

You need to add this library [`fastify-cors`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-cors).

Please remove `app.enableCors()` before using above code.